# Download javascript loaded pages

Tags: javascript, python, wget

The example I'm looking at is [morningstar.com](http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=GOOG&region=USA&culture=en-US).
Most of the contents are loaded through this javascript function. When I use wget, I don't get the data that actually show up in the browser (because wget doesn't interprets javascript code).

Is there some way to evaluate the javascript and download the full page (with cmdline or code)?

```
SRT_stocFund.LoadAComponent("sfcontent", "C", "is", "en-us","USA", "", "USA", null,{showSubTab: false});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that specific page, maybe you could just wget the URL of the "Export" button? Obviously this will only work if you are trying to use the actual data that the site is displaying (since that is all that is in the extract).

Here is a link directly to the .csv file: http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?t=GOOG&culture=en_us&region=USA&order=asc&r=765325

Comment: how did you get this csv link?

Comment: I clicked the morningstar link that you supplied and there is a link right on that page (just do a find on the page for "export"). It's in the top-right of the table.

Comment: Thanks. not the automated way I was hoping for but it'll work.

Comment: It's looking like if you know the symbol for the company (GOOG or AAPL), you can sort of automate the process. Just replace "GOOG" in that URL with the correct symbol. To grab the information for Apple, for example, this would be the URL: http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?t=AAPL&culture=en_us&region=USA&order=asc&r=765325

Answer (score 2):

Install Firebug for Firefox, and check out what's going in the 'Net' tab. That'll show you all the network requests Firefox puts out for a page. From that you can copy the URL of any Ajax requests (in the XHR tab), and see the response.  Feed the Ajax URL to wget (unless its a POST, in which case its a bit trickier).